# Control width of two tables (desktop-only and mobile only)

Tags: css, html-table

The following html code generates two tables within a wordpress post. One for desktop view only and one for mobile view only.

The issue is that no matter what I do the table does never fit the whole width of my wordpress post. I tried to place "width: 100%" at several different places within the code and in some cases it worked fine and the tables filled the whole width but then suddenly both tables were visible, not differentiating no more between mobile and desktop view.

This is my code:

```
<style media="all">
.mobile-only{display:none}
.desktop-only{display:table}
@media (max-width:500px)
.desktop-only{display:none}
.mobile-only{display:block}
</style> 

<div class="mobile-only">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td><b>Emittent</b></td>
<td><b>Fälligkeit</b></td>
<td><b>Typ</b></td>
<td><b>Richtung</b></td>
<td><b>Hebel</b></td>
<td><b>wkn</b></td>
<td><b>Strategie</b></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Mobile Bank</td>
<td>Open End</td>
<td>Knock Out</td>
<td>Long</td>
<td>5,7</td>
<td><a href="https://www.onvista.de/derivate/Knock-Outs/265189228-DJ8316-DE000DJ83164">DJ8316</a></td>
<td>Offensiv</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Morgan Stanley</td>
<td>Open End</td>
<td>Knock Out</td>
<td>Long</td>
<td>6,8</td>
<td><a href="https://www.onvista.de/derivate/Knock-Outs/265090595-ME83JW-DE000ME83JW3">ME83JW</a></td>
<td>Offensiv</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Datum: 18.02.2024</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="desktop-only">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td><b>Emittent</b></td>
<td><b>Fälligkeit</b></td>
<td><b>Typ</b></td>
<td><b>Richtung</b></td>
<td><b>Hebel</b></td>
<td><b>wkn</b></td>
<td><b>Strategie</b></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Desktop Bank</td>
<td>Open End</td>
<td>Knock Out</td>
<td>Long</td>
<td>5,7</td>
<td><a href="https://www.onvista.de/derivate/Knock-Outs/265189228-DJ8316-DE000DJ83164">DJ8316</a></td>
<td>Offensiv</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Morgan Stanley</td>
<td>Open End</td>
<td>Knock Out</td>
<td>Long</td>
<td>6,8</td>
<td><a href="https://www.onvista.de/derivate/Knock-Outs/265090595-ME83JW-DE000ME83JW3">ME83JW</a></td>
<td>Offensiv</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Datum: 18.02.2024</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Where do have to place "width: 100%" in a manner that the mobile-only and desktop-only attributes still work?

Kind regards
Marc

Answer (score 0):

It's so hard when you use size for many screen. And i recomment you use responsive add bootrap  right here at w3school: [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).